# ¿Cómo logro leer datos desde la terminal con fgets correctamente?

Tags: c, fgets, stdin

Quiero leer estos datos desde la terminal pero parece que la función no puede leer correctamente los datos y se salta el primer **fgets**

```
  printf(" Alias: ");
  fgets(nuevo->nombre, 20, stdin);
  printf(" URL original: ");
  fgets(nuevo->urlCompleto, 200, stdin);
  printf(" Descripcion: ");
  fgets(nuevo->descripcion, 100, stdin);
  //parte de la lectura de la opcion
  int opcion;
  opcion = getc(stdin) - '0';
```

Resultado en pantalla:

```
 Escoge una opción: 1
 Alias:  URL original:
```

Comment: int opcion;
  opcion = getc(stdin) - '0';

Comment: Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/407266/edit) la pregunta y coloca ahí esa información. Poca gente se lee los comentarios. Un saludo.

Comment: De hecho está agregado en el código, gracias

Comment: Falta codigo.. Si antes de ejecutar la funcion `fgets`, invocas a `scanf`, de seguro el buffer `stdin` quedara sucio y por eso se salta..

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es un poco engañoso. Por la salida que pones, supongo que tu
código sera:

```c
  //parte de la lectura de la opcion
  int opcion;
  opcion = getc(stdin) - '0';
  printf(" Alias: ");
  fgets(nuevo->nombre, 20, stdin);
  printf(" URL original: ");
  fgets(nuevo->urlCompleto, 200, stdin);
  printf(" Descripcion: ");
  fgets(nuevo->descripcion, 100, stdin);
```

### stdin

Tienes que tener presente que stdin es solo un buffer. Para lo que haremos, nos
basta con verlo como un array de caracteres. Entonces la entrada de tu código
queda así:

```
| 1 | \n |
```

Al llamar `getc` va a tomar solo el `1`. stdin nos queda así:

```
| \n |
```

Ahora al llamar `fgets` va a leer hasta el `\n`, que en este caso sera el
primer carácter que va a leer.

### Y que hacemos?

Para leer la opción te recomiendo mejor esto:

```c
scanf("%d%*c", &opcion);
```

`scanf` va a leer el entero, y el `%*c` es un carácter que va a leer pero con
el `*` le indicamos que lo ignore. Así leer el carácter y va a dejar el stream
limpio para tus siguieres lecturas.